# TypeScript: wrapper for generic class implementation

Tags: typescript, generics, dry, typescript-generics

Why is the following not possible in TypeScript?

```js
abstract class Generic<T> {
  // ...
}

class Specific1 extends Generic<string> {
  // ...
}

class Specific2 extends Generic<number> {
  // ...
}

// this is where stuff goes wrong, compiler wants me to provide generic type arguments
//                                     |
//                                     ˅
abstract class Wrapper<T extends Generic> {
  // ...
}

class Wrapper1 extends Wrapper<Specific1> {
  // ...
}


class Wrapper2 extends Wrapper<Specific2> {
  // ...
}
```

With the `Wrapper` generic class line, I am trying to express that I only want to let classes  go into `Wrapper` as the generic type that "specifically implemented" `Generic`, i.e. `Specific1` and `Specific2`, in this case.

In the project I am working on, I have more generic types for `Generic` than shown here and also more implementations, i.e. more `SpecificX` classes. I could avoid this problem by passing all the generic types to `WrapperX` that I passed to `SpecificX` before, like so:

```js
class Specific1 extends Generic<type1, type2, type3> {
  ...
}

...

class Wrapper1 extends Wrapper<type1, type2, type3> {
  ...
}
```

... but I just feels very dirty and I am wondering whether there is a better way to solve this problem. I already defined my `SpecificX` class and its generic types and want to avoid doing so again at a different location.

Simple DRY, but I can't figure out how to do it in TypeScript :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Wrapper` should be able to *wrap any `Generic`*, and you don't really care about what the actual `Specific` type might be, then explicitly marking the type parameter as `unknown` will do just that. With the following, you can create wrappers for anything that extends `Generic`.

```js
abstract class Wrapper<T extends Generic<unknown>>
```

If the `Wrapper` should only *wrap one of the `Specific` types*, then you could approach the problem with a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). It might be a good idea to make a new type that contains all of the options. This is definitely more verbose, but prevents anything arbitrary (e.g. `Generic<ButNotASpecificType>`) from being wrapped.

```js
class Specific1 extends Generic<string> {
  // ...
}

class Specific2 extends Generic<number> {
  // ...
}

type Specific = Specific1 | Specific2

abstract class Wrapper<T extends Specific>
```

Here's a [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&strict=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAg4gUwHbagEtYAeAFQD4EBvAKAQTAHsBbbCAC0NwHMAuBGXpImuSFACu8JlAAUAN2DIJ2AWQCUNYQ06EwAOmZtdvBAF4Ei5dmEBfWvdoo0GAMoAHbLEIAzYgEYEbAAPCDwAEwwcfCJScW4eKmp7Z3QEDy9fYgAmINCIqLwCYhJcCRYQAiTHUHE4RFSMAHUYd08oAFVcAGtcJgB3XHI8sNxIrCLYkgkevsGKJOEjdi5eNWFYUXEpCBkFJRU1TToGHS4DZZMec0sDmwZ7R0aEFuA2gi7egdxAkNHx17vTqzb4kDLePywfzVJyoNKA9qfOa4XJ-AovVqIkGDMGeCE5GHPBEfbG4ADMI3RxOBXxx0WKpBATCYyGwwFwCxoKThzUxJNpuAALJSxry3liBSQmSy2RyubRaLVoPUkDyMeKSYRRMM0aL0nislCEAAffWZSHZRYMS6rfiCDZbaA7PZWQ6CY7aBC6C6sFYJG6u%204IR4Kol84Fan4igHhrqR3HmgKEtXUuOiVH5PWp3Dx8GGy3ysMaiOiCm6mPFtNDelTaWs9mc5KwlzqoFV4XlsVtnPauuymFAA) showcasing the two approaches.

Comment: Dude, you just saved my day. `unknown` turned out to be exactly what I needed. I do have some constraints, but I already modeled them using an interface. Thank you!!!